# uivision multiple verify element is present with a if statement

Tags: selenium

I have a situation where a website now can either have one of two potential elements which if one or the either happens to exist, then dont click another element. I am using verifyelementnotpresent with the if_v2.

I have successfully implemented this with a visual search before with ${whatever} == 0 ||${whatever2} == 0 || but can the same theory be applied to multiple verifyelementnotpresent?

the formulas I have in uivision for the visual verify are:

```
 {
  "Command": "visualVerify",
  "Target": "status2_dpi_96.png@1",
  "Value": "",
  "Description": ""
},
{
  "Command": "store",
  "Target": "1",
  "Value": "!timeout_wait",
  "Description": ""
},
{
  "Command": "visualSearch",
  "Target": "registration_dpi_96.png@1",
  "Value": "registration",
  "Description": ""
},
{
  "Command": "visualSearch",
  "Target": "submission_dpi_96.png@1",
  "Value": "submission",
  "Description": ""
},
{
  "Command": "visualSearch",
  "Target": "debt_dpi_96.png@1",
  "Value": "debt",
  "Description": ""
},
{
  "Command": "visualSearch",
  "Target": "documents_dpi_96.png@0.8",
  "Value": "documents",
  "Description": ""
},
{
  "Command": "if_v2",
  "Target": "${registration} == 0 || ${submission} == 0 || ${debt} == 0 || ${documents} == 0",
  "Value": "",
  "Description": ""
},
```

but now instead of visual search, I want a ifelementnotpresent with the elements xpath and a name:

```
{
  "Command": "verifyElementNotPresent",
  "Target": "/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[${!times}]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/a",
  "Value": "others",
  "Description": "reconcile"
},
{
  "Command": "verifyElementNotPresent",
  "Target": "/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[${!times}]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/label",
  "Value": "suggestion",
  "Description": "reconcile2"
},
{
  "Command": "if_v2",
  "Target": "${!LastCommandOk} == false",
  "Value": "if no potential others",
  "Description": ""
},
```

so in the above, I would prefer it check if element 1 or element 2 are not there, and both these are true, then press a different element, but nowhere in uivision/selenium do I see it keep record/count of an element like it does with the visual aspects, and no I cannot use a visual element here as it is duplicated up to 10 times and these elements have to be referenced in a specific order.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: done as requested